# How to tree strcture function in PHP for OOPS?

Tags: php, pdo

I am creating a comment and reply system in PHP using the tree concept.
I have created a comment table in my database -

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `cm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cm_message` text NOT NULL,
  `postid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

As you can see, I have contained parent id and comment id with post id.

My tree function

```
function fetchCategoryTree($parentid = 0,$user_tree_array = '') {
global $db; 
global $postid;
  if (!is_array($user_tree_array))
    $user_tree_array = array();
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT
    comments.cm_message, comments.cm_id,comments.parentid,comments.created,users.username, users.image 
FROM comments 
    INNER JOIN users  ON comments.user_id = users.user_id 
    WHERE comments.postid=:postid AND parentid =:parentid   ORDER by comments.cm_id DESC');  

$stmt->execute(array('parentid' => $parentid, 
                   'postid' => $postid

                ));

  if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
      $user_tree_array[] = array("cm_id" => $row->cm_id,"image" => $row->image,"parentid" => $row->parentid,"username" => $row->username,"created" => $row->created, "cm_message" =>$row->cm_message);
      $user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTree($row->cm_id, $user_tree_array);
    }
  }
  return $user_tree_array;
}
```

Calling a function

```
$categoryList = fetchCategoryTree();
```

It's working but,
As you can see I have made a global postid in the function.
if I give the postid inside

```
 $categoryList = fetchCategoryTree($postid);
```

and change the function look like -

```
function fetchCategoryTree($postid) {
    global $db; 
$parentid = 0; 
$user_tree_array = ''; 

}
```

then it doesn't work.

I want to convert it to OOPS class and method but it's not working like this.

The main points are here -

1. I am inserting comments and replies in the same table.
2. I am fetching comments and replies by postid using while loop on the same page -

like -

```
post 1  
comments for post 1 
with reply 


post 2 
comments for post 2 
with reply 


post n 
comments for n post  
with reply n
```

### What are the best ways to do that in OOPS?

class and method

How can I use postid at the calling time without any errors?

Comment: `$categoryList = fetchCategoryTree($postid);` . In your function, the first parameter is `$parentid` so why you are calling it with `$postid`? Function will assume it parentid. Or do you have two different functions with same name?

Comment: Parentid is for comments and postid for finding post related comments and reply. I am asking if u can find with postid at calling time . Understand that I have made global postid .how can pass postid at calling time with same function. I don't want to make postid global just pass at the time of calling a function .

Comment: you are calling the same function with postid as a parameter. The code assume the postid as parentid. For this, you have to create 2 different functions with different names. One function will accept post id and query the post's comments. Second function will accept parentid and query comments with parent id.

Comment: I am not calling same function two times . I want to change like this . Function will be called at one time . I want to remove global postid and want to pass at the calling time . Just understand that I am calling only one time and Created only one function for that task.

Comment: How can I pass postid at the calling time without making it global in same function ?

Comment: I think you should create function like `function fetchCategoryTree($postid, $parentid = 0,$user_tree_array = '') ` . In this way you can call both postid and parentid for replies in a same function.

Comment: and in while loop just replace the line as `$user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTree($postid, $row->cm_id, $user_tree_array);`

Comment: Yes, now it's working cool. Thank you Dear